# Output API data to a csv file

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Frankenstined bits of code together found on here and on various Google tutorials. My goal is to get data from the Google Analytics API and output it to a file in my Google Drive "my_data.csv".

I am able to get my data from the GA API in a variable "results". The default output of results variable is an object (I think?) and looks like this:

```
Logger.log(results);

dataTable={cols=[{id=ga:year, label=ga:year, type=string}, {id=ga:month, label=ga:month, type=string}, {id=ga:medium, label=ga:medium, type=string}, {id=ga:source, label=ga:source, type=string}, {id=ga:campaign, label=ga:campaign, type=string}, {id=ga:goal1Completions, label=ga:goal1Completions, type=number}], rows=[{c=[{v=2015}, {v=06}, {v=(none)}, {v=(direct)}, {v=(not set)}, {v=117}]}, {c=[{v=2015}, {v=06}, {v=(not set)}, {v=(not set)}, {v=(not set)}, {v=0}]}, {c=[{v=2015}, {v=06}, {v=(not set)}, {v=ET}, {v=DL}, {v=0}]}, {c=[{v=2015}, {v=06}, {v=(not set)}, {v=a1e88567-3904-4375-a14a-cff82d7613d2}, {v=wda}, {v=0}]},
```

Or I can change the output `'output':'dataTable'` in the API call. The results then look like:

```
Logger.log(results);

rows=[[2015, 06, (none), (direct), (not set), 117], [2015, 06, (not set), (not set), (not set), 0], [2015, 06, (not set), ET, DL, 0], [2015, 06, (not set), a1e88567-3904-4375-a14a-cff82d7613d2, wda, 0], [2015, 06, (not set), google_plus, DL, 0], [2015, 06, Display, Facebook, Facebook, 0], [2015, 06, Display, GOOGLE, ReTargeting, 0], [2015, 06, ET, Email, SearchTopStories, 1], [2015, 06, affiliate, cj, 1651317, 0],
```

So there are two ways I can ouput the data. Currently I do not know which is "best" wrt to getting my data into a csv. For now I'm trying with the dataTable structure.

Here is my code:

```
// set some global vars
var profile = 'ga:XXXXXXXX'; // my actual id added here
var my_csv = 'my_csv';

//trigger function runs everything else
function getToIt() {

    var results = getReportDataForProfile(profile);
    convertRangeToCsvFile_(results, "my_data");
}

// get GA data
function getReportDataForProfile(profile) {

  var startDate = getLastNdays(1);
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:year,ga:month,ga:medium,ga:source,ga:campaign', // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    'start-index': '1',
    'max-results': '10',
    'output':'dataTable'
    //'samplingLevel': 'higher-precision'
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get( // mcf for multi channel api, Ga for core
      profile,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
    'ga:goal1Completions', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
      optArgs);

  Logger.log(results);

  if (results.getRows()) {
    return results;
  }
}

// child function for setting date range
function getLastNdays(nDaysAgo) {
  var today = new Date();
  var before = new Date();
  before.setDate(today.getDate() - nDaysAgo);
  return Utilities.formatDate(before, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}

// convert results to csv
function convertRangeToCsvFile_(data, file_name) {

  Logger.log("data here:" + data);
  var csv = google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(data);  

  //output to drive
  DriveApp.createFile(file_name, csv);
  return csvFile;
}
```

The error message I receive just now is

> ReferenceError: "google" is not defined

Looks like my issue is right here:

```
var csv = google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(data);
```

How do I create the variable csv? I'm not sure how to import the google.visualization module given my environment is GAS. I'm not even sure that it's the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic 2d array to csv converter. Also you can't use the JSAPI library on the server side it will not work.

```
function arrayToCsv(data){
var csv = ""
var eol = '\r\n';
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
     csv += data[i].join();
     csv += eol;
    }
  return csv;
}


function t(){
var data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
 data.unshift(["title1","title2","title3"]); // add my header array;
  var newcsv  = arrayToCsv(data);
  Logger.log(newcsv);
  var backToData = Utilities.parseCsv(newcsv);
  Logger.log(backToData);


}
```

Comment: Hi Spencer thanks for the answer. Once more tiny thing, if you will. If the variable headers looks like this: ga:year,ga:month,ga:medium,ga:source,ga:campaign, how can I make it so that those are the csv headers with everything afterwards populating as data? I have tried a few different things to achieve this but to no avail

Comment: You would use the unshift() method. It pushes an element onto the front of an array.

Comment: This solution works - thank you once again. Now that I'm applying it to the real thing: > 10,000 rows of data, I'm finding it very slow. Not sure if there's any efficiency gains to be had or not, but if any come to mind do share